# PHP long mail queue and HTTP request

Tags: php, queue, httprequest

I have a question about the HTTP request to a PHP script.
If my script sends many email and needs some time to complete and the client closes its browser the scripts will be aborted or not?
Can I think that the mail queue goes once that the script is started (obviously removing any timeout in php settings)?
I don't care about the reply to client.

Comment: The script keeps running until finished or max execution time is hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script will run to it's end (until finished or some errors occur)

Try yourself:

**somefile.php**

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 25; $i++ ) {
    file_put_contents( "seconds.txt" , $i );
    sleep(1);
}
```

open your browser, navigate to this script and close the browser.

Wait a few seconds and see whats in the file `seconds.txt`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to start a script in the background that does the actual work. This way, your script will return immediately (but you will have to use other means to prove success).

Like:

```
exec('/path/to/worker parameters &');
```

Comment: Good idea, but I cannot upload scripts in the hoster's web server... :-(